# Why is the following url showing two 4s in the path?

Tags: ruby, forms, activerecord, sinatra, put

Trying to wrap my head around postgres, ruby, restfulness and sinatra and encountered a snag.

I have an `index.rb` file that looks as follows:

```
get '/' do
  # Look in app/views/index.erb
  erb :index
end

get '/categories/:name' do
  @variable = Category.find_by_name(params[:name]).posts
  erb :posts
end

get '/new_post' do
  erb :new_post
end

post '/new_post' do
  @random_key = rand(10..90)
  params[:key]=@random_key
  Post.create(params)
  @post_id = Post.last.id

  "your edit URL is: /post/#{@post_id}/edit?key=#{@random_key}"
end

get '/post/:id/edit' do
  @post_id=params[:id]
  erb :edit
end

put '/post/:id/edit' do
  rand_key=params[:key]
  post_id=params[:id]
  Post.find_by_key(rand_key).update(params) #==Post_id
end
```

And I have an `edit.erb` file that contains the following:

```
<form action="<%=@post_id%>/edit" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="put"/>
  Edit your item:
  <br>
  <input type="text" name="name">
  <select name="category_id">
    <option value="1">cars</option>
    <option value="2">books</option>
    <option value="3">jobs</option>
    <option value="4">household</option>
  </select>
  <input type="text" name="desc">
  <input type="text" name="price">
  <input type="text" name="email">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

When I go to the edit url (something like `localhost:9393/post/4/edit?key=67`) it shows the form, but then when I submit the form it redirects to the url `localhost:9393/post/4/4/edit`.

I don't understand why this is inserting two 4s in the path. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try having the form's action as below:

```
<form action="/post/<%=@post_id%>/edit" method="post">
```

instead of

```
<form action="<%=@post_id%>/edit" method="post">
```